# Prisma, Next JS api route prisma.create giving me a bad request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, prisma

I have the following prisma schema

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = "file:./dev.db"
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model FormInput {
  id    String @id @default(uuid())
  name  String
  type  String
  order String
}
```

and jsx react nextjs file

```
import Head from "next/head";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { v4 as cuid } from "uuid";
import styled from "styled-components";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const FormStyles = styled.form`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 350px 1fr;
  label {
    //background: red;
  }
  input,
  select {
    //background: aqua;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-top: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 0;
  }
  input[type="button"] {
    background: green;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 0 25px auto;
    &:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
  button {
    background: lightgray;
    padding: 15px;
    border: none;
    &:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
`;

const GridStyles = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 0;
  div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;
    align-items: center;
  }
`;

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const formInputs = await prisma.formInput.findMany();
  return {
    props: {
      initialFormInputs: formInputs,
    },
  };
}

export default function Home({ initialFormInputs }) {
  const blankFormInput = {
    name: "test",
    id: cuid(),
    type: "text",
  };
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState([blankFormInput]);

  const [inputs, setFormInputs] = useState(initialFormInputs);

  const test = inputs?.reduce((obj, item, idx) => {
    return { ...obj, [`name-${item.id}`]: item.name };
  }, {});

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({ defaultValues: test });

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    let hmm = formState.map((ok) => {
      var name = data[`name-${ok.id}`];
      var type = data[`type-${ok.id}`];
      var boogie = { [ok.id]: { name: name, type: type } };
      return boogie;
    });

    const response = await fetch("/api/formSave", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(hmm),
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }
  };

  const addInput = async () => {
    const blanktext = {
      name: "Test",
      id: cuid(),
      type: "text",
      order: 0,
    };
    setFormState([...formState, { ...blanktext }]);
    const response = await fetch("/api/addInput", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(blanktext),
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }

    console.log(response);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <FormStyles onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <h1>Create Your Form Input Fields</h1>
        <div>
          {formState.map((val, idx) => {
            const nameId = `name-${val.id}`;
            const typeId = `type-${val.id}`;
            return (
              <div key={val.id}>
                {val.type === "text" && (
                  <GridStyles>
                    <div>
                      <label htmlFor={nameId}>Input Name</label>

                      <input
                        type="text"
                        name={nameId}
                        id={nameId}
                        className={val.type}
                        ref={register()}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <label htmlFor={typeId}>Input Type</label>

                      <select name={typeId} ref={register}>
                        <option value="text">text</option>
                        <option value=" image"> image</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </GridStyles>
                )}
              </div>
            );
          })}
          <GridStyles>
            <input type="button" value="Add Form Input" onClick={addInput} />
            <button type="submit">Save Form</button>
          </GridStyles>
        </div>
      </FormStyles>
    </>
  );
}
```

I am sending the following object to this api route

```
{
  name: 'Test',
  id: 'e5b85d84-f21c-4e71-9921-98eb2cdedb3a',
  type: 'text',
  order: 0
}
```

api route

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export default async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    return res.status(405).json({ message: "Method not allowed" });
  }

  try {
    const input = JSON.parse(req.body);
    console.log(input);
    const savedContact = await prisma.formInput.create({ data: input });
    res.status(200).json({ message: "hello" });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
  }
};
```

I keep getting a bad request I have tried a varying degree of prisma.formInputCreate, and others. This happens when I click the add input button. I am expecting it to add a row to the DB. Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you share the error you get in `catch` by logging `err`?

Comment: I logged the error, and it just said bad request

Comment: I tried logging the prisma.formInput.create variable on the api side to see if I could get a result in the terminal console and it shows nothing. I must be doing something wrong here

Comment: I tried putting a .catch and logging on the `prisma.formInput.create().catch((err)=>console.log(err))` but no dice, was that not spot to put it

Comment: One way to debug would be checking to see if the data you're passing to `await prisma.formInput.create()` is correct or not. Also try running the create method separately and check. If that works, then most probably is an input or API issue.

Comment: so the order key was supposed to be a String not an Int so I changed my schema for it to be an Int. I discovered the error by moving the request outside of the try catch, because as soon as the try catch failed javascript moved along and didnt console log anything. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: why to not use mutations? you didn't want to create inputs before saving form ... prisma supports nested creations and updates [properly] ... I'd separate view/presentation from logic/container ... do you really want to change input types after insert? ... IMHO you can choose type before insert ... input on list should be renamed/edited (options for select/radios/checkboxes)/removed but not changed to other type (at least internally - container should provide replace fn internally removing one and inserting other)

Comment: Ok thanks for the tips, feel free to make an answer with all these comments in one, I am more than happy to choose it.

Comment: just tips for project/structure ... not an answer to this question